# Подменить заголовок Referer.

Tags: php

Есть сайт на котором хранится видео. При отдаче проверяется Referer. если Referer пуст или этот сайт, то видео скачивается, если нет то ошибка доступа (403). Как можно вставить видео в свой видеоплеер?

*C помощью Curl могу скачать, но мне же надо напрямую его отдавать.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подменить заголовки запросов, отправляемых браузером, ты не сможешь. Специально от этого и сделана защита. Вот пример [для apache](http://www.davidairey.com/stop-image-theft-hotlinking-htaccess/)  [вот для nginx](http://www.nginxtips.com/how-to-stop-image-hotlinking-on-nginx/). Вообще, если на сайте поставили защиту, значит не хотят, чтобы таким образом их контентом пользовались. Попробуй договориться с владельцем ресурса, чтобы он в настройках сервера разрешил пользоваться его контентом на страницах твоего сайта.

Но если тебе очень надо получить чужой контент, для которого настроена защита по referer, тебе придётся реализовать проксирование. Купи VPS/VDS, установи на него веб-сервер nginx, настрой проксирование с подменой Referer. Вот мануал на модуль [nginx proxy](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html). И готовься платить за входящий и исходящий трафик.

В принципе, проксирование можно организовать и на дешёвом хостинге класса LAMP через PHP, но ...

1. некоторые хостинги запрещают внешние соединения, значит не удастся обратиться к другому сайте за оригиналом видео.
2. файл будет прокачиваться через оперативную память, а на хостингах её много не дают. При превышении лимита процесс убьют и файл не скачается.
3. файлы обычно качаются медленно, а на хостингах может стоять принудительное ограничение на время работы скрипта. При вревышении времени работы процесс убьют и файл не скачается.

Так что это не перспективно.

Comment: А если на хостинге сайт, то как быть?

Comment: расширил свой ответ